# Convert an object to object array

Tags: javascript

An API i call gives out a result like so:

```
{
  "name1" : "value1",
  "name2" : "value2",
  "name3" : "value3",
  "name4" : "value4",
}
```

I want to change convert that to

```
[
  {"name1" : "value1"},
  {"name2" : "value2"},
  {"name3" : "value3"},
  {"name4" : "value4"},
[
```

I tried to use

```
Object.keys(result).forEach(function(key) {
      console.log(key, result[key]);
      let item = key;
      policyStatusList.push(
          new Object({
          item: result[key]
          })
     );
});
```

but it ended up as

```
[
  {"item" : "value1"},
  {"item" : "value2"},
  {"item" : "value3"},
  {"item" : "value4"},
[
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: use *policyStatusList.push({[key]: result[key]})*
, and no need of item = key else everything is fine. In you code item will be taken as string not as a varibale if you want to pass the variable as key in an object you need to use [key];

Comment: No, you dont want that.

Comment: @AZ_ so apparently i just needed to add brackets to item thank you;

thanks for the help everyone, will accept CertainPerformance's answer though since it's a lot more efficient than my current code

Comment: @RaphaelEstrada yes your code is not efficient, just pointing out whats wrong.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`.map` the `Object.entries` of the object:

```js
const obj = { "name1" : "value1", "name2" : "value2", "name3" : "value3", "name4" : "value4" };
const arrOfObjs = Object.entries(obj).map(([key, val]) => ({ [key]: val }));
console.log(arrOfObjs);
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use `reduce` and `concat` methods.

```js
var obj = { "name1" : "value1", "name2" : "value2", "name3" : "value3", "name4" : "value4" }
var res = Object.keys(obj).reduce((result, item) => result.concat([{[item] : obj[item]}]), []);
console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it:

```
const obj = {
  "name1" : "value1", 
  "name2" : "value2", 
  "name3" : "value3", 
  "name4" : "value4" 
};
const convertedArray = Object.entries(obj).map(([key, val]) => ({
    [key]: val 
}));
console.log(convertedArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

> I want to change convert that to ...

No, you probably don't want that. The datastructure returned by the API is great, because

1) You can easily get the value for a certain key, e.g. `obj.name1`

2) You can easily get all keys (`Object.keys(obj)`), values (`Object.values(obj)`) and key-value pairs (`Object.entries(obj)`) to iterate over.

With the datastructure that you "want" to get you can neither:

1) look up a value, as you would've to iterate the array and search for the key in each object, which is really slow & ugly.

2) Iterate over keys, values and key-value pairs, as you would've to extract the key & value out of each object, which is complicated.

So no, you don't want that.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is you're creating your new object with the key `item` - you want to use the key `[item]` (the value of the variable named `item`, not the literal string `item`):

```js
const result = {
  "name1" : "value1", 
  "name2" : "value2", 
  "name3" : "value3", 
  "name4" : "value4" 
};

let policyStatusList = [];

Object.keys(result).forEach(function(key) {
  let item = key;
  policyStatusList.push(
    new Object({
      [key]: result[key]
    })
  );
});

console.log(policyStatusList);
```